# Google OAuth2 - isAccessTokenExpired() always true

Tags: php, google-oauth

I use OAuth in my application and I want log out the user when the access token is expired.

But when I checked the token expiration with

```
 $client->isAccessTokenExpired()
```

It always return 1.

```
if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['token']);
}


if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));  
}



if (!isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
 }


if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
    $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

    $oauth2 = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
    $userinfo = $oauth2->userinfo->get();
    $emailUser = $userinfo->getEmail();
    $_SESSION['emailUser'] = $userinfo->getEmail();
}
```

Comment: If you need to refresh token, you can get refresh token, then save it into bd,file, etc. And use him.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You probably checking the expiration before running `$client->setAccessToken();`. Let us see the code where you are checking the expiration.

Comment: Actually when I run  $client->isAccessTokenExpired() just after $client->setAccessToken(); It returns 'false'. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set refresh token before checking for isAccessTokenExpired

- $client->refreshToken($refresh_token);

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old but the function `isAccessTokenExpired()` will return true when you excluded `expires_in` key after setting the token via `setAccessToken($params)`.

For example setting access token should be the following,

```
$client->setAccessToken([
  'id_token' => '...',
  'created' => '...', // or, if you don't have id_token
  'expires_in' => '...',
]);
```

In Google's github, this is the code that check `expires_in` key:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/main/src/Client.php#L570-L573

```
if (!isset($this->token['expires_in'])) {
    // if the token does not have an "expires_in", then it's considered expired
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Not always true.
I did exactly in the right orders and 
1/ isAccessTokenExpired() is always TRUE
2/ i receive access_token, refresh_token, expires_in, but i never receive created.
This created is used in isAccessTokenExpired()