# token expire in google api php

Tags: php, google-api

I create a app that need google api auth. at the first time redirect to google and get token and save token to database:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile(__DIR__ . '/credentials.json');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/index.php');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
if ( !isset($_GET['code']) ) {
    $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} else {
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $token=$client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
    $token=$token['access_token'];
    update_option('iwp_google_drive_token',$token);
}
```

but when i want to use token . `isAccessTokenExpired()` function always return true .

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile(__DIR__ . '/credentials.json');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/index.php');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setAccessToken(get_option('iwp_google_drive_token'));
var_dump($client->isAccessTokenExpired());
```

Comment: The access token is only valid for an hour sounds like you need a new one its expired.

Comment: @DaImTo I found the problem and reply my question.

Comment: I've answered this in https://stackoverflow.com/a/74429018/959060

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix the problem.token must save in file exactly as returned from google. but my mistake was I parse token and save only `$token['access_token']`. so :

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile(__DIR__ . '/credentials.json');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/index.php');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setApprovalPrompt ("force");
if ( !isset($_GET['code']) ) {
    $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} else {
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $token=$client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
    $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    file_put_contents(__DIR__ .'/'.$tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
}
```

and read token from file and use `json_decode` :

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile(__DIR__ . '/credentials.json');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/index.php');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$tokenPath = 'token.json';
if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
  $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents(__DIR__ .'/'.$tokenPath), true);
  $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
}
var_dump($client->isAccessTokenExpired());
```